# From Type Theory to Set Theory

Tags: set-theory, type-theory, programming

I have to provide the definition of a arbitrarly nested data set with recursive types so that I do not fall in the Russel's paradox by its definition. The implementation in OCaml that came into my mind is the following one (*):

```
type e = E of id | L of l
and l = B of id | I of e * l;;
```

This means that:

- `e` is a type that could be either an `id` or a list `l`, where:
- any list `l` is a list of elements in `e`, terminated by an `id`

Since it is typed in OCaml, I assume that this definition is compliant. This means that, if I want to reproduce the data structure:

$$\{\{1,2\}_{B=55},3,4,\{6\}_{B=66}\}_{B=0}$$

then I could write something like:

```
I (L (I (E 1, I (E 2, B 55))), I (
   E 3, I (
   E 4, I (
   L (I (E 6, B 66)), 
B 0))))
```

Since I want to provide the most intuitive definition of (*) that could be read by any person that does not know type theory but only knows set theory, I'm wondering how to express a recursive data type in such theory. Please note that my target are people not coming from logic field, so they understand set theory but do not understand type theory. Moreover, the set theory used must be the most simple as possible.

I was trying to define something like this:

$$\begin{cases}
   e \overset{def}{=} (\mathbb{ID}\times\{\textbf{0}\} \cup \ell\times\{\textbf{1}\})\\
   \ell \overset{def}{=} \mathbb{ID}\times\{\textbf{0}\} \cup (e \times \ell)\times\{\textbf{1}\}\\
\end{cases}$$

Is there something more simple and intuitive in order to represent nested-well-typed set within set theory?

**EDIT**

This means that, even supposing that I could always distinguish and id ($\mathbb{ID}$) from a list ($L$) and hence supposing that even this other solution is acceptable:

$$\ell \overset{def}{=} \mathbb{ID} \cup ((\mathbb{ID} \cup \ell)\ \times \ell)$$

I'm still wondering if if there is something more simple than that.

Comment: Do you actually use lower case L as variable names in programs?  While also using uppercase L to refer something else?

Comment: EDIT: now $\ell$ stands for the $l$ in lowercase in the program.

Comment: $l$ and $e$ stand for a Algebraic Data Type definition, while the ones in upper case are the types costructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard way of representing arbitrarily nested sets inside a type theory -- this is done by reprenting sets as pointed graphs with bisimulation giving the equality between "sets". (This was first done, I think, by [Miquel](https://www.fing.edu.uy/~amiquel/publis/csl03.pdf))

As for implementing this in an actual programming language, probably the best way is by considering a very particular type of pointed graph -- a tree structure! In Haskell, for instance, you might define:

```
data NestedSet A = Nesting [Either (NestedSet A) A]
```

For example, we might represent $\{ \{ 1, 2 \}, 3, 4, \{ 6 \} \}$ as:

```
Nesting [Left (Nesting [1,2]), Right 3, Right 4, Left (Nesting [6])]
```

Intuitively, to give a (finite) set, we may simply list its elements, so we do so with the `Nesting` constructor, and the elements of a nested set may either be simple elements `A`, or other nested sets `NestedSet A`.

Comment: So, given that my $\ell$ is just your `NestedSet` and $\mathbb{ID}$ is your `A`, at the end of the road, is more like $\ell \overset{def}{=} ((\mathbb{ID} \cup \ell)\ \times \ell)$, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the intuition behind your $\mathbb{ID}$ is, but ``A`` is just whatever the elements of the set are (i.e. although nested, these sets are still homogeneous, for heterogeneous nested sets you would have to define it a bit differently). In OCaml it would be something like ``type a nestedset = Nested of ((a nestedset, a) either) list`` if I'm not butchering the syntax (not very experienced with the language).

Comment: If $\cup$ denotes a binary disjoint union, $\times$ a binary product, and $1$ a unit type, then we can describe the ``a list`` type (now with a more ocaml-like notation) as $a \; list = a \times (a \; list) \cup 1$ (A list of ``a``s is either the cons cell of an an element of type ``a`` and another ``a list``, or the empty list), so then we could say $\mathrm{a \; nestedset} = ((\mathrm{a \; nestedset}) \cup a) \; list$ I'm sure there's a way to write this type as a single definition in OCaml (without using lists), but they're a part of the core language, so why not use them?

Comment: Actually, that's because really I want to associate to each nesting an identifier (I want to distinguish each list containing the same elements with different ids). The list of elements did not comply with my initial requirement: “any list `l` ($\ell$) is a list of elements in `e` ($A$, $\mathbb{ID}$), **terminated by an id**”

Comment: BTW, I know Haskell too so it was clear to me what you've written before,

Comment: So, if I understand, you want to distinguish (for example) the first occurrence of $\{ 1, 2\}$ in $\{ \{ 1, 2 \}, 3, \{ 1, 2 \} \}$ from the second one, which is your purpose for including an identifier for each branching?

Comment: That is precisely what I had in mind!

Comment: In that case, I don't know if any more data needs to be specified than what is already in ``NestedList a``. Without imposing an equivalence relation on the type, we don't in fact have the usual set-theoretic identities, e.a. $\{ \{ 1, 2\},3,\{1,2\} \} \neq \{ \{1,2\},3\} $, so the structure of the datatype itself already distinguishes different occurrences of sublists. But if you want a way to refer to different occurrences (in order to modify them, perhaps), I don't think your approach is ideal either -- you want unique identifiers for each occurrence, and your type doesn't enforce that.

Comment: Then again, it's hard to say without knowing exactly what you had in mind in terms of applications.

Comment: I think that such constraint is definable in type theory by only using dependent types. And, alas, there is a huge constraint on the “readability” of my definition (I'm not talking to people coming from a strong theoretical background). Well, the only thing is that to each id I have some data associated with it (but this part is representation is “external” to my own problem). 

(continues)

Comment: So, given `NestedMultiset a` an instance of the pair `NestedSet a`$\times\mu$, where $\mu$ maps each element in `NestedSet a` to the number of its occurences, the id of the $i$-th instance of $m$ is defined as $d(f(m),i)$, where $f$ is the bijection Skolem functor associating to each element a number in $\mathbb{N}$ and $d$ is the dovetailing bijection associating to each $\mathbb {N}^2$ an $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: So, if $\downarrow$ is the function returning each element contained by the nested set, I have to impose that each $v_\iota$ is such that $\iota\notin {}_\downarrow v_\iota$ and, for each nested element $v_\kappa$ appearing in $v_\iota$ at any nesting level, given $v'_\iota$ the $v_\iota$ where $v_\kappa$ is removed, then $\iota\notin v'_\iota$.